# Parsing the Hershey font format

Tags: fonts, file-format

**Hershey** is a text-based vectorial font format defined here: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/

> The structure is bascially as follows: each character consists of a
>   number 1->4000 (not all used) in column 0:4, the number of vertices in
>   columns 5:7, the left hand position in column 8, the right hand
>   position in column 9, and finally the vertices in single character
>   pairs. All coordinates are given relative to the ascii value of 'R'.
>   If the coordinate value is " R" that indicates a pen up operation.

I don't understand how to parse this format. For example for the character '3':

```
3 11MXVNTMRMPNOPOSPURVTVVU
```

the number of vertices is 11. What are those 11 vertices ? I would say:

```
MX VN TM R(pen up)  MP NO PO SP UR(a 'R' here?) VT VV U(last char missing?)
```

but it is wrong (last coordinate is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it wrong. "R" is not a "pen up" — " R" is "pen up" (space + R). The vertices are:

```
MX VN TM RM PN OP OS PU RV TV VU
```

"R" is not special, it's just the zero of the coordinate system, so "RM" is [0; -5].

Answer (score 0):

Aye - and the number of vertices is not quite a vertices count - but a count of the number of pairs to follow; including the initial left/right and the ' R' move flag. See the function parse:()path in https://github.com/dirkx/HersheyEngravingFontsForCocoaAndiPhone for an example.