# Parse Hershey font .jhf to json using python or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, fonts

I ve been searching the web for a solution but I found nothing that is within my skills. How would you transform these Hershey Font .jhf files [emergent.unpythonic.net/software/hershey](http://emergent.unpythonic.net/software/hershey) to JSON using python or javascript. Creating something like:

```
[
    {
        asciival:26,
        points:[[5,-5],[4,7,8],[6,8,7]]
    },
    {
        asciival:27,
        points:[[5,-3],[4,7,33],[6,32,7]]
    },
(…)
]
```

I know there is a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042840/parsing-the-hershey-font-format) but this is not enough for me to understand the system.

### Edit1

I already found the descriptions [paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/) sean pointed out in the comments.

> As an example consider the 8th symbol
> 8  9MWOMOV RUMUV ROQUQ
> It has 9 coordinate pairs (this includes the left and right position).
> The left position is 'M' - 'R' = -5
> The right position is 'W' - 'R' = 5
> The first coordinate is "OM" = (-3,-5)
> The second coordinate is "OV" = (-3,4)
> Raise the pen " R"
> Move to "UM" = (3,-5)
> Draw to "UV" = (3,4)
> Raise the pen " R"
> Move to "OQ" = (-3,-1)
> Draw to "UQ" = (3,-1)
> Drawing this out on a piece of paper will reveal it represents an 'H'.>

I tried to make sense out of this, but where do the values come from?
For example why is UM (3,-5)?

### Edit2

I found [this java class](http://www.batbox.org/font.html)

Comment: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/hershey/ That goes over it ok. The code is not too difficult from the looks of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates are consecutive pairs of characters. To translate them into numbers you subtract the ascii equivalent of the character 'R' = 82 from each character. In your example, "UM" translates to (3,-5) because U is ascii code 85. Subtract 82 (='R') to get 3.  M is ascii code 77, subtract 82 to get -5.